# Manuscript is in same 'With Editor' status for 3 months. Is it normal?

Tags: publications, research-process

I am a researcher (doing my PhD) in Computational Biology. I have submitted a manuscript to an Elsevier journal 3 months before. One day after my submission editorial status changed to 'With Editor'. But after that no further change (change to 'Under Review') has been noticed. I already has one publication with Springer Verlag. In that case within a week of being 'With Editor' the status changed to 'Under Review'. This time this is opposite. Is it likely of being 'With Editor' status for long 3 months?